# how to process a windows message in web service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

In WinForm framework,you can override wndproc to catch windows message,but there is no function override for web service.
How to  process a windows message in web service? (like catch device changed event)

Comment: I don't believe this is directly possible, because a web service runs without any windows context.  To make it work, you would have to self-host the web service in your own winforms process, in which case you could use the technique you are familiar with.  (But it would not be able to run without someone logged into Windows).